# cant get parameter in URL using Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to get the parameter I passed in my URL using the `GET` but I have an error:

```
An Error Was Encountered

The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.
```

My URL is looks like this:

```
http://localhost/teradasys/index.php/users/user/user_info&user_id=1
```

And in my controller:

```
public function user_info() {
    $user_id = $this->input->get('user_id');
    print_r($user_id);
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: so you need 1 by get ? my question how and when you need it

Comment: Try `http://localhost/teradasys/index.php/users/user/user_info?user_id=1`.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to include the `?` before the parameter. Sorry for my simple mistake.

Comment: You can accept @ShamarKellman 's answer bellow since it points same solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You URL is missing the `?` which defines the start of a query parameter. Therefore your URL should look like this `http://localhost/teradasys/index.php/users/user/user_info?user_id=1`. Then you can use the get() function.

Answer (score 0):

Use Segment !!

'&' disallowed characters.

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html